# How to model 'toggle' table in sql

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a table with some columns

```
CREATE TABLE test (
testid INT,
field1 CHAR(10),
field2 VARCHAR(50),    
field3 DATETIME,    
field4 MEDIUMINT
[...]
);
```

Now I want to be able to have a setting in my app that will allow me to to either enable or disable some of those for particular users.

```
CREATE TABLE user (
userid INT
);
```

I was thinking about:

```
CREATE TABLE user_test_visible (
userid INT,
field1 BOOL,
field2 BOOL,
field3 BOOL,
field4 BOOL
[...]
);
```

Also I was thinking about something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE user_test_visible (
userid INT,
field_name VARCHAR(30),
visible BOOL);
```

Are any of those approaches sensible?

Comment: Are those (4) columns actually all `CHAR(10)` or is that just a simplification and the columns are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest do something like this maybe.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    fieldId INT,
    field CHAR(10)
)
```

To have one table that contains the fields. Then if you need to add one more (change of requirements) you do not have to add a new column.

The I would skip the boolean and go with one table that has a shared primary key. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_test_visible (
    userid INT,
    fieldId INT
);
```

The reason why I would suggest skipping the boolean is that if there is no row do show the field. That depends on what your start value is. If you want the users to see all field from the begining then you might consider having the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_test_not_visible (
    userid INT,
    fieldId INT
);
```

Then where there is a row in this table then do not show the filed.

**Edit**

When use insert the field you must have some pre deployment script right? There you can also specify which columns that are visible and which is not. If you have different data types then ether have the layout like you have or you can just a sql_variant. But beaver that this type of column is not supported in for example linq-to-sql as a primary key.

That is just my idés. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Hm... yes, that sounds all right. Although my issue with this is that I will have say 20 fields, some will be visible by default some wont with ability to toggle later. If I have this design I will need to have some app logic to setup defaults. If I go for my first example I can setup defaults in DB... which probably matters not... I ma not sure, hence I ask :).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more flexible approach would be to define "roles" within your application. A user would be associated with one or more roles, and each role would be associated with a set of columns. The union of those column sets would be what a user can see. This approach will require more effort to work out what columns a user can see, but it would make user management easier in the long term. It also separates user privileges from what that means in terms of database access.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, unfortunately that wont work because those will be modifiable on per user basis - so one user can have 3 on and 1 off another can have another 3 on and another 1 off , another one 2 on 2 off etc. Tat would create too many 'roles'. Thanks anyway.